# SMTP Email not sending

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I made a simple program to send e-mails, but it fails to send them and gives me an exception.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public class test{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 465;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword");
        client.Send("myemail@gmail.com","myemail@gmail.com","Test","Test");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Just added the following lines of code:

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

and changed the port to 587, then it says that authentication is required, and I alredy put my credentials, maybe its because the port 587 needs TLS not SSL (from what I learned searching about this today, I know that SSL is an "evolution" of TLS, no?)

Comment: What exception does it give? **Include the inner exception**, which can be an important clue.

Comment: Check this google link https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1 and have a close look at the last point

Comment: this is just a test, i made another application a bit more complex but the only difference is that it uses variables and has a graphical interface. Anyway, it gives me this exception:                                                         An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: the time limit has been reached. (I translated this last line because it was in portuguese).

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Tunigamer, just tried the code below and that worked:

```
SmtpClient gmailClient = new SmtpClient {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password")
            };


            using(MailMessage gMessage = new MailMessage("email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "Test", "Test")) {

                try {
                    gmailClient.Send(gMessage);
                } catch(Exception) { }
            }
```

Also, I received this notification below from GMAIL, you will need to disable the sign-in security features of your account:

[image]